# How keeloq keyfob exchange key with receiver in the first place?

Tags: block-cipher, key-exchange

After reading a lot of articles and the microship maunal for keeloq IC, I think I understand how the encryption and decrytion works. If I understand correctly, however, the decryption require the exact same 64-bit key as the encryption does. My question is how the receiver get that key for decryption in the first place?
I see from microchip HCS300 maunal there are 3 learning mode, simple, normal and secure.

Most of the garage door opener I have seen with rolling code only require to press a single button on the keyfob, so it is not putting the keyfob on learning mode, so it is unlikely to be secure mode? And since most of these actually accept a generic keyfob you can buy from ebay, I don't think it is going to be a fixed crypt key as described in simple learning mode, or otherwise there is not much security.

So they are in normal learning mode? which the key is actually dervied by a manufactrer key and the serial number of the keyfob? But that is still an issue as the keyfob I bought online would not know which manufacturer gate opener I am going to use, and therefore with the keyfob key derived from the manufacturer key in the first place?

Bottomline: How does the receiver learn the keyfob encryption key in the first place?

Comment: Note that this is a pretty product specific question, so much so that I thought of closing it. However, I would not know where to direct you, so I've left it be. This kind of requires the person to be knowledgeable with this specific product, so it may be tricky to get an answer. It may be a good idea to contact the vendor or manufacturer instead.

Comment: Maybe information security stackexchange is more appropriate?

Comment: @kodlu Possibly, I'll check later if they accept changes, but I'm off this weekend.